What is this movie about a prisoner kept in a cave with a bull and an old man?
I watched this movie when I was a little child, around 2004 but I believe it came out before then. I remember a little bit of the movie. There was a prisoner who get thrown into a cave where a bull lives and an old man. The prisoner and the old man met each other and the old men taught him how to survive in the cave by eating rats. 
At the end, the prisoner killed the bull by making a spark with a stone, because the cave was full of gas. 
And if I could remember, Michael Clark Duncan was in it too, but I'm not so sure because it was a man with a big Afro.
This was an American film and was in English.

Welcome!  Could you give us some info?  When you say you were a child, when was that?  How long ago did you see the film.  Was it in English? Do you know the country of origin? The more info you can give us, the more likely we'll be able to find your answer!

it's like 2004 when I saw the movie, but I'm pretty sure that the movie was older the 2004. The movie was in English and from America.

Usually when a person describes a movie including Bull + Cave : think minotaur. Research into minotaur on imdb should yield results.

Not sure why this was close-voted a few minutes in. It was fairly detailed even before the OP supplied more info in a matter of minutes.

That could be Minotaur, (2006).  It has an old man:

Theo, Danu, and Morna encounter Turag, a single youth from an earlier
  sacrifice who has managed to elude the Minotaur so far, but has become
  slightly insane over the years.

And the cave was full of flammable gas:

Theo tempts the Minotaur into attacking him, and in the process the
  Minotaur breaks its left horn, but continues to charge after Theo. As
  Theo runs back towards the gas vent, he scratches the walls with
  Fion's iron amulet and generates a spark that ignites the whole
  labyrinth, and dives into a pond of water where Raphaella was waiting
  for him.

The movie is available on Youtube.

Oh My God!!! Thank you so much!!
